# Problem connecting camera to RPi 4 running ubuntu 20.04 aarch64

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi

im tring to connect camera (Raspberry GSCam) to raspberry pi 4, running ubuntu 20.04 aarch 64.

I have added `start_x=1` and `gpu_mem=128` to `/boot/firmware/config.txt` and rebooted. Still there is no `video0` device under `/dev`.

Trying to take pictures with following code:

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture("/dev/video0", cv2.CAP_V4L)

_, frame = cam.read()
cv2.imwrite("path.jpeg", frame)
cam.release()
```

gives:

```
open VIDEOIO(V4L2): backend is generally available but can't be used to capture by name
```

So I'm assuming that camera is not detected by raspberry. Also I have check phisical connecton and it is all right and camera was working under raspbian OS.

My question is: how to fix it?

Comment: Watch your system start up and detrect (or not) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`.  Read  `man journalctl`.